# How to pass 2 arguments to a procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to transform this code to accept

```
EXECUTE concatenate_strings('big','dog');
```

instead of how it currently has the values written within the code.

```
create or replace
procedure concatenate_strings as
   str1 varchar2(10) := 'begin';
   str2 varchar2(10) := 'end';
   result varchar2(20);
   begin
      result := str1 || ' ' || str2;
      dbms_output.put_line('The result is: ' || result);
end;
```

Comment: Manual might be helpful. It is a little academic: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-subprograms.html#GUID-C0397690-70F4-480D-ADC9-02D277DAA1BB

Comment: What's wrong with the built-in [`concat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CONCAT.html#GUID-D8723EA5-C93A-45C3-83FB-1F3D2A4CEAF2) function?

Answer (score 2):

Hi you need to pass these in as parameters see sample below

```
create or replace
procedure concatenate_strings(p_str1 in varcahr2, p_str2 in varchar2) as
   result varchar2(20);
   begin
      result := p_str1 || ' ' || p_str2;
      dbms_output.put_line('The result is: ' || result);
end;
```